# Regex string format check

Tags: regex

I need to check that a string takes on the format

```
05:31:2008:06:27:2010
```

I do not have to check anything such as valid date or anything just that there are 2 digits, colon, two digits, colon, four digits.... etc

So my first attempt at this my regex looks like this

```
[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{4}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{4}
```

It does not seem to work, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: In what way does it not work?

Comment: What language? Different languages have different implementations of regex.

Comment: That should work just fine in java... can't really think of any reason why it wouldn't. Did you try griffin's answer using /d digit matching?

Comment: @FarisMustafa I didn't even read OP's regex... it seems fine to me. I thought `:` might have a special meaning in Java, hence escaping them, but they don't. Medium, you should post more code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\d{2}\:\d{2}\:\d{4}\:\d{2}\:\d{2}\:\d{4}
```

or shorter, with grouping and no escaping of `:`

```
(\d{2}:){2}\d{4}:(\d{2}:){2}\d{4}
```

If that doesn't work you need to post more code.